# Is there any online awk command "explainer"?

Tags: command-line, bash, awk

First, I am not sure where I should ask this question. Please point me out the correct forum if this place is not meant for this.

I am looking for a tool that can explain awk commands.

As a reference, check out this website: https://regexr.com/

When you hover on the regex part, it explains you what it does. I am looking for the same feature (does not need to be a website, anything will do as long as I can have the information) for awk.

[image]

An example of awk command I need to "decipher":

```
  awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{if(FNR>3){for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sub(/ +$/,"",$i);sub(/^ +/,"",$i)};if(NF!=1){print $2,$3,$4}}}'
```

Comment: Have you read `man awk`?

Comment: Awk is a programming language, not some simple tool. I don't think what you're asking for would even be possible: you can write arbitrary programs in awk and they can be millions of lines long and very complicated.

Comment: @waltinator Yes I am currently using this to "decode" what I have ^^

Comment: @terdon That's what I thought. THanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, it would be pretty difficult to make a simple tool for the AWK programming language like you found for regular expression syntax. Maybe the closest you'll find are sites where you can enter and run AWK code, like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_awk_online.php

Regarding your sample:

```
awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{if(FNR>3){for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sub(/ +$/,"",$i);sub(/^ +/,"",$i)};if(NF!=1){print $2,$3,$4}}}'
```

That's:

```
awk [a command-line option] '[some AWK code]'
```

The first part's easy -- just do "`awk --help`" (which tells you "`-F fs`" sets the field separator). The "some AWK code" part is harder. I'd suggest prettifying it is a good step. You're supposed to be able to do:

```
gawk --pretty-print=a.awk 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{if(FNR>3){for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){sub(/ +$/,"",$i);sub(/^ +/,"",$i)};if(NF!=1){print $2,$3,$4}}}'
```

I just tried that. It just sat there, even though a simpler one like for example "`gawk --pretty-print=a.awk 'BEGIN{a=3}'`" works just fine. A C beautifier like https://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier will get you pretty close, so your code sample is:

```
BEGIN {
  OFS = "|"
}

{
  if (FNR > 3) {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
      sub(/ +$/, "", $i);
      sub(/^ +/, "", $i)
    };
    if (NF != 1) {
      print $2, $3, $4
    }
  }
}
```

Now it should be easier to follow. You can more clearly see that there are two main blocks: "BEGIN" and an unnamed one.

Then go to https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html (or search the web for "awk manual", which will probably return that as the first hit) and if you're just getting started, the "Getting Started with awk" section is helpful. Within the first few paragraphs you'll learn that unnamed blocks are executed for each line of input text, and that there are optional BEGIN and END blocks that run just once.

You might have to use control-F on that web page to find things like FNR (which it tells you is the number of the line being processed, within the current file) and NF (number of fields on the current line).